# Can Oracles use CHA mod for casting javelins from Holy Ice?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic, ability-scores, oracle

The text of the javelins option from [Holy Ice](http://legacy.aonprd.com/ultimateMagic/spells/holyIce.html) refer to using the WIS mod plus the BAB for each javelin attack.

Can Oracles apply their CHA bonus instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Ask your DM.

From [Paizo's FAQ](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn#v5748eaic9qlk):

> As written, those effects say "Wisdom" (because they were written before the idea of the oracle class as a Charisma-based caster), so an oracle has to use her Wisdom modifier.
>
> However, it is a perfectly reasonable house rule to allow an oracle to use her Charisma modifier (or bonus) for cleric spells that refer to the caster's Wisdom modifier (or bonus).

So officially by the rules as written, no, oracles cannot use their CHA mod instead of their WIS mod. However, Paizo has effectively acknowledged that oversight and said that while, for whatever reason, they can't be bothered to fix it, DMs are all but encouraged to let oracles use their CHA mod.